# How to make PageView with different page size only for the current page

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

The reason I want to use PageView because it can stick to the page when dragging is released.
But I can't figure out how to achieve the screen like below:

[image]

I want to make the page currently selected page show a larger size, while others show smaller.
The most straightforward method is to set the `viewportFraction` (to 0.15). But after that I find out that the pages need the different values of `viewportFraction`:

[image]

You can see that I want the space between pages equally but only the middle one shows larger.
Is this possible to do with the PageView Widget? Or does anyone have other workarounds that can achieve the same result?

If possible, I also want to add `GestureDetector` to each page (which can animate to the target page)

Comment: This look a like to carousel widget, I'm using this library a lot between my apps [carousel_slider](https://pub.dev/packages/carousel_slider)

Comment: I have seen the carousel library. It only shows at most 3 widgets on the screen, and not really care about the width of the widgets out of the screen. I want about 5-7 pages show on the screen and looks balance when the middle one is much larger than the others.

Comment: Hi, @yellowgray did u decide upon a solution u liked?
and what is the best route to take hare?

Comment: @Zihan Actually I tried Transform (scale + shift) at last and it did well on display but also cause another problem (mouse hit test issue). So I abandoned finding the solution from PageView.

Answer (score 5):

Check this [dartpad](https://dartpad.dev/84151a10660a471a69a9cca93adf368f?null_safety=true) out:

[image]

You can check out all the code there but the gist is that inside every page view you have an animated container in which you animate its padding to control its height :

The value is hardcoded but you could use a mediaquery to get a dynamic top padding.

```dart
class PageviewGallery extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _PageviewGalleryState createState() => _PageviewGalleryState();
}

class _PageviewGalleryState extends State<PageviewGallery> {
  final PageController ctrl = PageController(
    viewportFraction: 0.75,
  );

  int currentPage = 0;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
        home: Scaffold(
      body: PageView.builder(
          controller: ctrl,
          itemCount: 8,
          physics: const BouncingScrollPhysics(),
          itemBuilder: (context, int index) {
            // Active page
            bool active = index == currentPage;
            return _buildStoryPage(active);
          }),
    ));
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    ctrl.addListener(() {
      int pos = ctrl.page!.round();
      if (currentPage != pos) {
        {
          setState(() {
            currentPage = pos;
          });
        }
      }
    });
  }
  
    @override
void dispose(){
ctrl.dispose();
super.dispose();

}
}

_buildStoryPage( bool active) {
  // Animated Properties
  final double blur = active ? 30 : 0;
  final double offset = active ? 20 : 0;
  final double top = active ? 100 : 200;

  return AnimatedContainer(
    duration: Duration(milliseconds: 500),
    curve: Curves.easeOutQuint,
    margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: top, bottom: 50, right: 30),
    decoration: BoxDecoration(
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
        color :Colors.red,
        boxShadow: [BoxShadow(color: Colors.black87, blurRadius: blur, offset: Offset(offset, offset))]),
  );
}
```

Comment: This only changes the height of the children. I want **width** change at the same time, with an equal distance between them. Please also set `viewportFraction` to 0.15 which displays the similar layout of my pageview.

Comment: Hi, @croxx5f can u please try to change the width of the PageView.

Answer (score 4):

From the Flutter [docs](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/PageView-class.html): "Each child of a page view is forced to be the same size as the viewport."

With that in mind, it is possible to achieve the effect you are looking for to some degree using a `PageView`. I riffed off of @croxx5f's answer, but here's how you can achieve it: https://dartpad.dev/e3fe965b19d36bc6f58bac8029a89251?null_safety=true.

Note that it is using padding (or lack thereof) to make the active element larger.

In short, the very nature of `PageView` required the elements to be the same width. If you want to use `PageView`, you will have to use padding or a similar technique to make the non active components smaller than the active one.

Comment: Thank you for your clear response and sorry for my late reply. But the layout is not closed enough to what I really want.  It seems reasonable from the official document that I shouldn't use pageView if I want the viewportFraction to become different between pages. I now stop at the point that using PageView+Transform to do a hacky solution or building a CustomScrollView that support different page size.